# Save images in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ipad

Is it possible to save images into `NSUserDefaults` as an object and then retrieve for further use?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

**ATTENTION! IF YOU'RE WORKING UNDER iOS8/XCODE6 SEE MY UPDATE BELOW**

For those who still looking for answer here is code of "advisable" way to save image in NSUserDefaults. You SHOULD NOT save image data directly into NSUserDefaults!

**Write data:**

```
// Get image data. Here you can use UIImagePNGRepresentation if you need transparency
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);

// Get image path in user's folder and store file with name image_CurrentTimestamp.jpg (see documentsPathForFileName below)
NSString *imagePath = [self documentsPathForFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%f.jpg", [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]]];

// Write image data to user's folder
[imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

// Store path in NSUserDefaults
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imagePath forKey:kPLDefaultsAvatarUrl];

// Sync user defaults
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

**Read data:**

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kPLDefaultsAvatarUrl];
if (imagePath) {
    self.avatarImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]];
}
```

**documentsPathForFileName:**

```
- (NSString *)documentsPathForFileName:(NSString *)name {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    return [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
}
```

**For iOS8/XCODE6**
As tmr and DevC mentioned in comments below there is a problem with xcode6/ios8. The difference between xcode5 and xcode 6 installation process is that xcode6 **changes apps UUID** after each run in xcode (see hightlighted part in path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/**B0D49CF5-8FBE-4F14-87AE-FA8C16A678B1**/Documents/image.jpg).

So there are 2 workarounds:

1. Skip that problem, as once app installed on real device it's never changes UUID (in fact it does, but it is new app)
2. Save relative path to required folder (in our case to app's root)

Here is swift version of code as a bonus (with 2nd approach):

**Write data:**

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)
let relativePath = "image_\(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()).jpg"
let path = self.documentsPathForFileName(relativePath)
imageData.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(relativePath, forKey: "path")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

**Read data:**

```
let possibleOldImagePath = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("path") as String?
if let oldImagePath = possibleOldImagePath {
    let oldFullPath = self.documentsPathForFileName(oldImagePath)
    let oldImageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: oldFullPath)
    // here is your saved image:
    let oldImage = UIImage(data: oldImageData)
}
```

**documentsPathForFileName:**

```
func documentsPathForFileName(name: String) -> String {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true);
    let path = paths[0] as String;
    let fullPath = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent(name)

    return fullPath
}
```

Comment: code did not work for me the first time, was not able to retrieve the image from disk. path to document folder was different between app runs.  could be an issue of absolute versus relative paths?  the code was writing to one *imagePath, but in next run of app, needed a different *imagePath to get the file.  simple solution was to save only filename in nsuserdefaults, and on next app run, re-get documents folder path, append file name, and rest of code worked great! (thank you Nikita Took)

Comment: So essentially the iOS8/Xcode 6 problem is completely void if primarily running on device?

Comment: I just want to add: Using PNGRepresentation will not save Orientation metadata automatically. You will have to do that manually, or just use the JPEG version.

Comment: Will saving images to that location affect the iCloud data - meaning if it's not user generated we shouldn't be saving to that location?

Comment: @ChrisHarrison according to Apple recommendations you should not save not-user-generated content to document directory. The code above is just an example of storing images. If you save them to cache directory it could be once deleted and you need additional code to handle that situation

Comment: @NikitaTook Thanks. I created a new directory inside the documents directory and added the `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` resource value (as explained here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html). I needed it to be in the documents directory because it has to be highly persistent. Do you think it's OK? Or is there another location you'd recommend?

Comment: @NikitaTook What about an array of images? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Note: File Names may not be able to exceed 255 characters depending on OS. Not an issue for the specific script that was provided, but can be an issue for people who modify it (like me).

Answer (score 139):

To save an image in NSUserDefaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) forKey:key];
```

To retrieve an image from NSUserDefaults:

```
NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: Technically correct, positively not recommended. NSUserDefaults outputs to a plist, which is obviously NOT the place for raw image data.

Comment: @cdstamper I read that a plist is stored in binary format these days on mac osx. If used between an extension and containing app IPC is used (a file may or may not be used in between). So what's the problem?

Comment: This question addresses iPhone/iPad. Regardless, until Apple's doc recommend otherwise, NSUserDefaults is for small application preferences and not storage. As specified (https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html), "The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs"

Comment: @cdstamper so what's the recommended way of storing, lets say, profile image for an app where the user is logged in? I don't want to use CoreData just for storing 1 image and I feel like hitting the cloud storage/db everytime i need to show the image is just expensive/un-necessary.

Comment: @annjawn just write it to the filesystem, and store the URL in NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 32):

While it is possible to save a `UIImage` to `NSUserDefaults`, it is often not recommended as it is not the most efficient way to save images; a more efficient way is to save your image in the application's `Documents Directory`.

For the purpose of this question, I have attached the answer to your question, along with the more efficient way of saving a `UIImage`.

---

### NSUserDefaults (Not Recommended)

**Saving to NSUserDefaults**

This method allows you to save any `UIImage` to `NSUserDefaults`.

```
-(void)saveImageToUserDefaults:(UIImage *)image ofType:(NSString *)extension forKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSData * data;

    if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
        data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    } else if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpg"]) {
        data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    }

    NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:data forKey:key];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

This is how you call it:

```
[self saveImageToUserDefaults:image ofType:@"jpg" forKey:@"myImage"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

---

**Loading From NSUserDefaults**

This method allows you to load any `UIImage` from `NSUserDefaults`.

```
-(UIImage *)loadImageFromUserDefaultsForKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    return [UIImage imageWithData:[userDefaults objectForKey:key]];
}
```

This is how you call it:

```
UIImage * image = [self loadImageFromUserDefaultsForKey:@"myImage"];
```

---

### A Better Alternative

**Saving to Documents Directory**

This method allows you to save any `UIImage` to the `Documents Directory` within the app.

```
-(void)saveImage:(UIImage *)image withFileName:(NSString *)imageName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {
    if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"png"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
    } else if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || [[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpeg"]) {
        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"jpg"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Image Save Failed\nExtension: (%@) is not recognized, use (PNG/JPG)", extension);
    }
}
```

This is how you call it:

```
NSString * documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
[self saveImage:image withFileName:@"Ball" ofType:@"jpg" inDirectory:documentsDirectory];
```

---

**Loading From Documents Directory**

This method allows you to load any `UIImage` from the application's `Documents Directory`.

```
-(UIImage *)loadImageWithFileName:(NSString *)fileName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {
    UIImage * result = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.%@", directoryPath, fileName, [extension lowercaseString]]];

    return result;
}
```

This is how you call it:

```
NSString * documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
UIImage * image = [self loadImageWithFileName:@"Ball" ofType:@"jpg" inDirectory:documentsDirectory];
```

---

### A Different Alternative

**Saving UIImage to Photo Library**

This method allows you to save any `UIImage` to the device's `Photo Library`, and is called as follows:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

**Saving multiple UIImages to Photo Library**

This method allows you to save multiple `UIImages` to the device's `Photo Library`.

```
-(void)saveImagesToPhotoAlbums:(NSArray *)images {
    for (int x = 0; x < [images count]; x++) {
        UIImage * image = [images objectAtIndex:x];

        if (image != nil) UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
    }
}
```

This is how you call it:

```
[self saveImagesToPhotoAlbums:images];
```

Where `images` is your `NSArray` composed of `UIImages`.

Comment: Great post! How do you figure out what directory to set for the input ```inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath``` - could you just call it whatever you want like "myAppData"??

Comment: Well in this case, I used the Documents Directory path as the argument. However, you could use any directory you have access to within your app's sandbox/bundle.

Answer (score 11):

**For Swift 4**

I almost tried everything in this question but no one is worked for me. and I found my solution. 
first I created an extension for UserDefaults like below, then just called get and set methods.

```
extension UserDefaults {
    func imageForKey(key: String) -> UIImage? {
        var image: UIImage?
        if let imageData = data(forKey: key) {
            image = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: imageData) as? UIImage
        }
        return image
    }
    func setImage(image: UIImage?, forKey key: String) {
        var imageData: NSData?
        if let image = image {
            imageData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: image) as NSData?
        }
        set(imageData, forKey: key)
    } 
}
```

to set image as background in settingsVC I used code below.

```
let croppedImage = cropImage(selectedImage, toRect: rect, viewWidth: self.view.bounds.size.width, viewHeight: self.view.bounds.size.width)

imageDefaults.setImage(image: croppedImage, forKey: "imageDefaults")
```

in mainVC :

```
let bgImage = imageDefaults.imageForKey(key: "imageDefaults")!
```

Comment: imageDefaults?)

Comment: let imageDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

Answer (score 8):

**For swift 2.2**

**To store:**

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(UIImagePNGRepresentation(chosenImage), forKey: kKeyImage)
```

**To retrieve:**

```
if let imageData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(kKeyImage),
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData as! NSData){
            // use your image here...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes , technically possible as in

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) forKey:@"foo"];
```

But not advisable because plists are not appropriate places for large blobs of binary data especially User Prefs. It would be better to save image to user docs folder and store the reference to that object as a URL or path.

Answer (score 5):

For **Swift 3** and **JPG** format

**Register Default Image :**

```
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["key":UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 100)!])
```

**Save Image :**

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 100), forKey: "key")
```

**Load Image :**

```
let imageData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "key") as! Data
let imageFromData = UIImage(data: imageData)!
```

Answer (score 3):

It's technically possible, but it's not advisable. Save the image to disk instead. NSUserDefaults is meant for small settings, not big binary data files.

Answer (score 3):

From apple documentation,

> The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of NSData.

You can save image like this:-

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.gif"])forKey:@"key_for_your_image"];
```

And read like this:-

```
 NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"key_for_your_image"];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use. But since it is for storage of preferences, you can better save images to document folder.

And you can have the path in the `NSUserDefaults`, if required.

Answer (score 1):

Save image to NSUserDefault:

```
NSData *imageData; 
// create NSData-object from image
imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([dic objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]]); 
// save NSData-object to UserDefaults
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imageData forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
```

Load Image from NSUserDefault:

```
NSData *imageData;
// Load NSData-object from NSUserDefault
imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
// get Image from NSData
[image setObject:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this question has a high google search index - here's @NikitaTook's answer in today's day and age i.e. Swift 3 and 4 (with exception handling).

Note: This class is solely written to read and write images of JPG format to the filesystem. The `Userdefaults` stuff should be handled outside of it.

`writeFile` takes in the file name of your jpg image (with .jpg extension) and the `UIImage` itself and returns true if it is able to save or else returns false if it is unable to write the image, at which point you can store the image in `Userdefaults` which would be your backup plan or simply retry one more time. The `readFile` function takes in the image file name and returns a `UIImage`, if the image name passed to this function is found then it returns that image else it just returns a default placeholder image from the app's asset folder (this way you can avoid nasty crashes or other weird behaviors).

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ReadWriteFileFS{

    func writeFile(_ image: UIImage, _ imgName: String) -> Bool{
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)
        let relativePath = imgName
        let path = self.documentsPathForFileName(name: relativePath)

        do {
            try imageData?.write(to: path, options: .atomic)
        } catch {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    func readFile(_ name: String) -> UIImage{
        let fullPath = self.documentsPathForFileName(name: name)
        var image = UIImage()

        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fullPath.path){
            image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: fullPath.path)!
        }else{
            image = UIImage(named: "user")!  //a default place holder image from apps asset folder
        }
        return image
    }
}

extension ReadWriteFileFS{
    func documentsPathForFileName(name: String) -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let path = paths[0]
        let fullPath = path.appendingPathComponent(name)
        return fullPath
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.x
Xcode 11.x

```
func saveImageInUserDefault(img:UIImage, key:String) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(img.pngData(), forKey: key)
}

func getImageFromUserDefault(key:String) -> UIImage? {
    let imageData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? Data
    var image: UIImage? = nil
    if let imageData = imageData {
        image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    }
    return image
}
```