# How do you save a picture with NSUserDefaults?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I have a iPad app that can take a picture and then put it within a image view. How do I go about saving the pic that I have stored in the image view? Here is what I have tried so far:     [imageView setImage:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]     objectForKey:@"storedImageValue6"]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much you have to convert it to NSData and vice versa. Take a look at this link: [Save images in NSUserDefaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648518/save-images-in-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)            forKey:key];      I think this is what I'm looking for, but where would I include the image and to be saved?

Comment: You put your UIImage pointer in place of (image) and set a Key that you will use to access your image

Comment: in the forKey: parameter just do forKey:@"MyKey" replace key with a nsstring that you can use later on.

Comment: I have totally screwed this up... could you direct me to a tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Here imageSet  is  UIImage

```
 NSData *imagedata=UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageSet);
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imagedata forKey:@"Theme Selecting"];    
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

You can use this code for saving image