# How do I programmatically change system-wide desktop picture?

Tags: macos, cocoa, desktop, nsworkspace

I'm using the following code to set desktop picture:

```
NSURL* newImage = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:@"/Users/name/Pictures/test.png"];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setDesktopImageURL:newImage forScreen:screen options:nil error:&nserror];
```

It works fine and the desktop picture changed as I required. But it does not change the system-wide desktop preferences (for example, change picture every 30 minutes). How can I change the system-wide desktop preferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Preferences and Settings Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i). This should help.

**Edit**:
Here is the sample code:

```
NSString* newImgPath = @"/Users/cody/Desktop/stuff/imgs/Black_mac.png";

NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableDictionary* desktopDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[defaults persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.desktop"]];
NSMutableDictionary* bgDict = [desktopDict objectForKey:@"Background"];
NSMutableDictionary* spaces = [bgDict objectForKey:@"spaces"];
[spaces enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString* key, NSMutableDictionary* obj, BOOL *stop) {
    [obj enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, NSMutableDictionary* prefs, BOOL *stop) {
        [prefs setObject:newImgPath forKey:@"ImageFilePath"];
        [prefs setObject:newImgPath forKey:@"NewImageFilePath"];
        [prefs setObject:@"Never" forKey:@"Change"];
    }];
}];

//NSLog(@"%@", desktopDict);

[defaults setPersistentDomain:desktopDict forName:@"com.apple.desktop"];
if ([defaults synchronize] == NO)
    NSLog(@"synchronize failed");

// Restart dock
system ("/usr/bin/killall Dock");
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I still have no clue after reading the link. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I found out that there is a commandline defaults that can read/write system preferences (actually it's my user preferences of system applications). For example, defaults read com.apple.desktop.

Comment: Output of defaults read com.apple.desktop:
{
    Background =     {
        spaces =         {
            "" =             {
                69677376 =                 {
                    Change = Never;
                    ChangePath = "/Library/Desktop Pictures";
                    // ...
    };
    "update-id" = 10080000;
}

Comment: I do not even know how to write to the Change key because there is a special name "" in its container path.

Comment: Try something like this: `defaults write com.apple.desktop Background '{default = {Change = Never;};}'`. Take a look at ClintonBlackmore's answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431205/how-can-i-programatically-change-the-background-in-mac-os-x. `defaults` utility is using NSUserDefaults class. So everything you can do with `defaults` utility you can do using NSUserDefaults class.

Comment: Just search through the internet, there are lots of examples on how to use this class, you just need to apply those to the 'Change' key. Here is the related question for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058825/how-do-you-save-a-picture-with-nsuserdefaults

Comment: I think I can do it using AppleScript. Found this excellent article: http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/system-prefs.html.

Comment: It's all up to you, but programmatically, using Cocoa it can be done with the help of NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Can anyone give me a few lines of sample code of NSUserDefaults as how to modify Desktop Background preferences?

Comment: I've provided the sample code based on the link I've gave you. I've successfully used this code on my machine with 2 desktops

Comment: Thanks for the code! It's great. I'm wondering how do you figure it out all the keys.

Comment: If it helped you - than accept the answer. As for the keys - just print the dictionary (see the commented line) and you'll see all keys.