# NSUserDefaults storing null image value

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsuserdefaults, nsdata, eaglview

I have EAGLview to display overlay image and taking screenshot then save this in `NSUserDefaults` for retrieve from `viewcontroller`.

But when i store the image into `photo album` it storing but it's not storing to `NSUserDefaults`. So, i'm getting `NULL` value.

---

```
UIImage *glImage = [self glToUIImage];
self.screensht = [self createSavableImage:glImage];

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.screensht, nil, nil, nil);


NSData* imgData1=UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.screensht);
[[NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults] setObject:imgData1 forKey:@"image"];
[[NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults]synchronize];


NSLog(@"nsuserdefauls is %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"image"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this steps:**

**To Store UIImage:**

```
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"])forKey:@"your_key"];
```

**To Retrive UIImage:**

```
 NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"your_key"];
 UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Answer (score 0):

You get `nil` because you wrongly use `stringForKey` to retrieve your object, which however is not a string. Try the following:

```
NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];
```

Also although technically correct I would not recommend storing images in a plist: [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648518/save-images-in-nsuserdefaults) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting NULL Value because you stored `NSData` Object with the key "image". But you are trying to retrieve a `NSString` Object. You should use the same object type whenever you store and retrieve for the same key.

You can try something like

```
NSData* imgData2=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"image"]
NSLog(@"nsuserdefauls is %@",imgData2);
```

You might see the object type from the above NSLog.