# Saving an image via NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to save a simple functionality, where a user clicks a button and the image changes, I want the image to stay the same when the user clicks the button. for instance, if the user clicks the button and the imageview is named `hello` it changes to an imageview named `goodbye` when the app closes and is deleted from the background, when the user reopens the app the `goodbye` image will be displayed.

What do I need to do for it to save?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var button: UIImageView!

@IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    button.image = UIImage(named: "testButtonWin")
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(button, forKey: "button")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    //println(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("button")!)
}


}
```

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21810380/2274694

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save images in NSUserDefaults?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648518/save-images-in-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: Why don't you just save the name (string) of the image to NSUserDefaults? Much more efficient than saving the entire image.