# Saving UIImage to File instead of NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, xcode6, nsuserdefaults

So I have an array with images that I want to store locally since downloading them each time will take unnecessary effort. I've read that I should NOT store images in NSUserDefaults, which is fine, but I can't for the life of me find any examples on how to store it as a file in a directory that does not change (iOS 8 changed the UUID with each build which creates a new folder each time I run it in Xcode).

I generally have two questions here:

1. Could someone help me translate this into ObjC? I can't comment on the post since I don't have enough rep...It's the swift part farther down the post that I need help with. [Save images in NSUserDefaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648518/save-images-in-nsuserdefaults/21810380#21810380)
2. The other question I have is that it seems to take a lot of time to save the data locally, no matter if it's to file or into the NSUserDefaults. What happens here is that the user of my app closes the app before the data has been stored locally. Is there any way to prevent this? I can add an ActivityIndicator, sure, but I can't seem to find any callback which tells me when the process of saving data has been completed.

Thanks!

Comment: Just don't store the full path the image and build the path to the document directory every time you want to access the images. This way if the app UDID changes it will not effect you path.

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to solve it. The problem was that I simply mixed up the paths. If anyone else wants the translation from Swift to ObjC from the link in the original post here it is:

**Write**

```
NSString* relativePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d.jpg", 1];
NSString* realPath = [self documentsPathForFileName:relativePath];

// Write image data to user's folder
[self.ImageData writeToFile:realPath atomically:YES];

// Store path in NSUserDefaults
[defaults setObject:relativePath forKey:@"path"];
```

**Read**

```
NSString *relativePath = [defaults objectForKey:@"path"];
NSString *realPath = [self documentsPathForFileName:relativePath];
self.ImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:realPath];
```